# How can a JSP(that is not called by a servlet) get data from the server

Tags: jsp, servlets

Please here me out and try to understand what i'm trying to ask here.

I know that a JSP can read and print out the data that is passed to it by a servlet. By any means of using request-response, session, cookies, or model and view. So what I know is that jsp1.jsp can send a request, then the servlet will process it, gather some data if needed, then will pass it to jsp2.jsp along with the data. Then jsp2.jsp can now display those data.

But how can a JSP that is not being called by a servlet that is requested by a jsp, display data?

If my project has only 1 JSP, for example. How can this JSP display data from the server if it's not being called by a servlet?

I hope you can understand what i'm saying here. It's really hard to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't  understood you correctly, but firstly you should understand  that JSP is "servlet with syntax sugar", it's part of Java EE specification. In practice, somewhere in-depth of Java EE, we have Jasper compiller (sometimes it's called JSP engine) convert your JSP into the servlet, that has many out.println(); instead of native JSP html tags. So if you want display some data from server in jsp, you can use Scriptlet, JSP tags etc., in which you can do access to the server or DB. Details and good examples here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm